# No virtual method getTypeface()Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/text/style/TypefaceSpan

Tags: android, fonts, spannablestring, typeface, android-typeface

I have an edit text which set some typeface spans with `CustomTypefaceSpan` which extends from `TypefaceSpan` and now I want to fetch spans from edit text by method `getSpans` and convert them to json object for the purpose of store in my database by using a method like this:

```
private fun typefaceSpanToJsonObject (editable: Editable): String?{
        val typefaceSpans = editable.getSpans(
            0,
            editable.length,
            CustomTypefaceSpan::class.java
        )
        val typefaceArrayList = ArrayList<MyTypefaceSpan>()
        if (typefaceSpans != null) {
            for (item in typefaceSpans){
                val typeface: TypefaceName? = typefaceToTypefaceName(item.typeface!!)
                if (typeface != null) {
                    typefaceArrayList.add(
                        MyTypefaceSpan(
                            typeface.toString(),
                            editable.getSpanStart(item),
                            editable.getSpanEnd(item)
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        return gson.toJson(typefaceArrayList)
    }
```

unfortunately after run I encounter to this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kateb_realm_word_editor, PID: 15269
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getTypeface()Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/text/style/TypefaceSpan; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.text.style.TypefaceSpan' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
        at com.example.kateb_realm_word_editor.Controller.Fragments.ViewLetterFragment.typefaceSpanToJsonObject(ViewLetterFragment.kt:746)
        at com.example.kateb_realm_word_editor.Controller.Fragments.ViewLetterFragment.saveLetterWithSpansIntoDatabase(ViewLetterFragment.kt:647)
        at com.example.kateb_realm_word_editor.Controller.Fragments.ViewLetterFragment.access$saveLetterWithSpansIntoDatabase(ViewLetterFragment.kt:48)
        at com.example.kateb_realm_word_editor.Controller.Fragments.ViewLetterFragment$onViewCreated$9.onClick(ViewLetterFragment.kt:214)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5646)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22473)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

this is my `CustomTypefaceSpan` class :

```
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Typeface
import android.text.TextPaint
import android.text.style.TypefaceSpan


class CustomTypefaceSpan(family: String, private val newType: Typeface) : TypefaceSpan(family) {
    override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType)
    }

    override fun updateMeasureState(paint: TextPaint) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType)
    }

    companion object {
        private fun applyCustomTypeFace(paint: Paint?, tf: Typeface) {
            val oldStyle: Int
            val old: Typeface = paint?.typeface ?: tf
            oldStyle = old.style
            val fake = oldStyle and tf.style.inv()
            if (fake and Typeface.BOLD != 0 && paint != null) {
                paint.isFakeBoldText = true
            }
            if (fake and Typeface.ITALIC != 0 && paint != null) {
                paint.textSkewX = -0.25f
            }
            if (paint != null) {
                paint.typeface = tf
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what should I do? Thanks in advance for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are running app on Api 28 or above ? because item.typeface which means getTypeface() in Java that is available in API 28 or above

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TypefaceSpan#getTypeface()